# docker-compose: client version is too new

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When executing `DOCKER_API_VERSION=1.35 docker-compose --verbose up` I'm getting:

> -d compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying
>   paths: ['/home/vivo/.docker/config.json', '/home/vivo/.dockercfg']
>   docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
>   docker.utils.config.find_config_file: Trying paths:
>   ['/home/vivo/.docker/config.json', '/home/vivo/.dockercfg']
>   docker.utils.config.find_config_file: No config file found
>   urllib3.connectionpool._make_request: http://localhost:None "GET
>   /v2.25/version HTTP/1.1" 400 84 Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 261, in
>   _raise_for_status   File "site-packages/requests/models.py", line 940, in raise_for_status requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error:
>   Bad Request for url: http+docker://localhost/v2.25/version
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "bin/docker-compose", line
>   6, in    File "compose/cli/main.py", line 71, in main   File
>   j
>
> "compose/cli/main.py", line 124, in perform_command   File
>   "compose/cli/command.py", line 42, in project_from_options   File
>   "compose/cli/command.py", line 123, in get_project   File
>   "compose/cli/command.py", line 97, in get_client   File
>   "site-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version   File
>   "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 267, in _result   File
>   "site-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 263, in _raise_for_status
>   File "site-packages/docker/errors.py", line 31, in
>   create_api_error_from_http_exception docker.errors.APIError: 400
>   Client Error: Bad Request ("client version 2.25 is too new. Maximum
>   supported API version is 1.38")

My docker version:

> docker-tutorial % docker version Client:  Version:
>   18.06.3-ce  API version:       1.27  Go version:        go1.10.3  Git commit:        d7080c1  Built:             Wed Feb 20 02:27:13 2019 
>   OS/Arch:           linux/amd64  Experimental:      false
>
> Server:  Engine:   Version:          18.06.3-ce   API version:
>   1.38 (minimum version 1.12)   Go version:       go1.10.3   Git commit:       d7080c1   Built:            Wed Feb 20 02:25:38 2019   OS/Arch:
>   linux/amd64   Experimental:     false

My docker-compose version:

> docker-tutorial % docker-compose version docker-compose version
>   1.24.1, build 4667896b docker-py version: 3.7.3 CPython version: 3.6.8 OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.0j  20 Nov 2018

And my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2.3'

services:
    app:
        image: php:7.2-apache
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
        ports:
            - 8000:80
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-docker/issues/173) 

 
Issue seems to have been fixed in Docker Version 18.09 onwards. Worth upgrading. If you do not want your containers to get affected while Docker version upgrade, enable `live-restore` on your `daemon.json` and do a `systemctl reload daemon`. After that perform the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/) I think you want to set `COMPOSE_API_VERSION`:

> **`COMPOSE_API_VERSION`**
>
> The Docker API only supports requests from clients which report a specific version. If you receive a "client and server don't have same version error" using docker-compose, you can workaround this error by setting this environment variable. Set the version value to match the server version.

Answer (score 0):

Running on linux Based Distributions sometimes this happens when there is a update in the distribution after apt update ,

you can just do a restart as service , sometimes this solves the problem. `sudo service docker restart` ,

In other case it might be ISO Cache issue which can be resolved using `docker-machine upgrade dev/YourMachineName`

Comment: `sudo service docker restart` wroked for me, thanks!